# Convert String to Number / Date or Null if invalid

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8

I have the following TypeScript interface:

```
export interface Model {
  numberValue: number;
  dateValue: Date;
}
```

I created instances of this interface defining the properties from empty strings:

```
let model1: Model = { 
  numberValue: +'',
  dateValue: new Date('')
}; 

console.log(model1);

model1 output: { dateValue: Invalid Date; numberValue: 0 }
```

And from strings containing invalid values:

```
let model2: Model = { 
  numberValue: +'A',
  dateValue: new Date('A')
};

console.log(model2);

model1 output: { dateValue: Invalid Date; numberValue: NaN }
```

I need to get for both empty strings and strings with invalid values the following:

```
model output: { dateValue: NaN; numberValue: NaN }
```

or

```
model output: { dateValue: null; numberValue: null }
```

I am sending `model` as Json to an API. When the values are empty or converted from invalid values I need to send `null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** There are libraries like moment.js that can help you a lot when it comes to the fairly tricky topic of Dates. But you can do a basic conversion yourself like this...

```
  parseUTCDate(year: string = "1970", month: string = "01", day: string = "01") {
    let tempYear = year;
    let tempDay = "";
    let tempMonth = "";
    // In case a Month shorter than 10 is added, we prepend a 0 to minimize errors
    if (month.length < 2) {
      tempMonth = "0" + month
    } else {
      tempMonth = month
    }
    // What we did to the month, we do for the day as well...
    if (day.length < 2) {
      tempDay = "0" + day
    } else {
      tempDay = day
    }
    // We construct our to-be-parsed date...
    let dateToBeParsedS: string = `${tempYear}-${tempMonth}-${tempDay}Z`;
    let date: Date = new Date(dateToBeParsedS);

    // We check if the Date is even valid. A proper Date value is always equal to itself
    if(date.getTime() === date.getTime()) {
      // if successful, we return the date
      return date;
    } else {
      // if not... well, we return an undefined or NaN if we like
      return undefined;
    }
  }
```

However, this method doesn't include all cases that can come up with a date. It's meant as an example of what you can do.

String to numbers is easier... but let's go the extra mile as well.

```
 returnNumberOutOfString(inputNumber: string) {
    // The Numberclass can parse numbers... that's what we will use
    let tempNumber = new Number(inputNumber)
    // Of course, we want to know if the number was valid... 
    if (isNaN(tempNumber.valueOf())) {
      return undefined;
    } else {
      // If successful, we return the primitive data value of the Number object
      return tempNumber.valueOf();
    }
  }
```

And with that, you've got basically all you need to convert and validate...

---

I'm a bit confused in terms of what you're trying to achieve. Also, to remain faithful to semantics, you're NOT creating a new instance of the interface. You've created an object of the TYPE model. It's not the same. But let's keep this going...

You said, IF the value is empty for whatever reason, it should return a null...

```
"numberValue": numberValue != undefined ? someNum : null
```

What does this line do? In case the value referenced in the object is not undefined, it should return the number. However, if the case isn't fulfilled, it will return a null.

In case you wish to know, if your date is a valid date, you can handle it in a similar fashion...

```
"dateValue": dateValue.getTime() === dateValue.getTime() ? dateValue : null
```

The idea here is, that a proper date will always be equal to itself, otherwise it will NaN

Comment: Yes, I meant "an instance (object) of the TYPE model". I did not explain myself correctly.

Comment: About your answer ... What I meant is when I do the conversions String to Date and String to Number if the conversion fails I want to define the numberValue or dateValue as null or undefined instead of for example 0 in case of the number. I am not sure I understood your answer.

Comment: @MiguelMoura I used the "Ternary Operator". It's basically a shortened form of an IF-Clause. I didn't really see that you wish to do actively conversions. I'll edit my answer slightly in a bit. Also, how do you expect dates to arrive? In your interface you say you expect a Date but how does your string date look like? That's important for any conversion you're attempting